# JQuery Scrollable ignores .delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollable

I'm trying to get the JQuery Tools Scrollable to pause fade out then go to the next vertical section on the page. This is the code.

```
$("#main").delay(3000).fadeOut(500).delay(500).data("scrollable").next();
```

When it lands on the last image it instantly goes to the next section with no pause.

I tried this as well

```
$("#main").delay(3000).fadeOut(500).delay(500).queue(function(){ 
    $("#main").data("scrollable").next();
    $("#main").dequeue();
});
```

The end result is that the vertical doesn't move all the way up...it just moves a few pixels

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` is designed for animations. Try using [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) instead. For example:

```
$("#main").delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function() {
    function nextSection(o) { o.data("scrollable").next(); }
    window.setTimeout(nextSection, 1000, $(this));
});
```

Comment: Getting the following error

$(this).data("scrollable").next(); is undefined